# Let $F: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be smooth. Show that the following are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $F: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be smooth. Show that the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) For any oriented piecewise smooth curve $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{2},$ the value of $\int_{C} F \cdot T d s$ depends only on the endpoints of $c_{c}$
>
> (ii) For any oriented piecewise smooth closed curve $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{2},$ we have $\int_{C} F \cdot T d s=0$

I could do nothing, can you add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

#### Hints

For $(i)\implies (ii)$: given a closed path $C$, starting and ending at $x_0$, the integral over $C$ is the same as the integral over any path starting and ending at $x_0$. What is the simplest path starting and ending at $x_0$? There is a path for which the integral over that path is zero, no matter what function you integrate.

For $(ii)\implies (i)$, consider two paths $C_1$ and $C_2$ with the same start and end points. How can you use $C_1$ and $C_2$ to make a *closed* path? If you do not see what I mean, try drawing a picture with $C_1$ and $C_2$. How does the integral over this closed path relate to the integrals over $C_1$ and $C_2$?